# Parcel paths to css and js not linking correctly

Tags: parcel, parceljs

I am new to application bundling and have decided to start out learning to use Parcel.

When I start the dev server everything seems to set up correctly with the `dist` folder and all of its files. The issue is that the JavaScript and CSS paths are not correct.

**The CSS link looks like this**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src.e31bb0bc.css" />
```

**But it should be**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./src.e31bb0bc.css" />
```

I fixed it manually but of course, every time I change something in my `src` folder, the links are changed back and my Javascript and CSS are gone again.

There are no folders inside the dist folder, so it looks like this:

```
dist/
- index.html
- src.e31bb0bc.css
- src.e31bb0bc.css.map
- src.e31bb0bc.js
- src.e31bb0bc.js.map
```

Any help is very welcome, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced the same problem.
So when point parcel to index.html, you should have all your .CSS and .js files in the same folder as index.html.
Like if you have "src" directory put your index.html in it. Then create subdirectories in "src" put your css files.[main directory of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5jFc.png) [src directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX3Ea.png)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known behavior in the Parcel community. To fix this add `--public-url ./` when running your build script. The final command looks something like this:

```
parcel build src/index.html --public-url ./
```

For more info, please refer to the following Github Issue: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1865